# Will I be able to transfer Pokemon from Sun/Moon to ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-bank, pokemon-seventh-generation

Is transferring Gen 6 and under Pokemon from Sun/Moon to ORAS a feature in Pokebank?

I'd like to breed on sun and moon, transfer to ORAS to get move tutors, then back to sun and moon.

Answer (score 2):

No. You will be able to trade Pokemon from 6th gen to 7th gen only, and not back.

Source [Pokemon official site](http://www.pokemon-sunmoon.com/en-au/pokemon-bank/).